# Clear value from select element when filtering in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a basic select element with options that dropdown hooked up to a small set of data which is being filtered using the dropdown. Initially on page load the select element has a value of `undefined` (according to the console), however after selecting any option it takes on the value of that option.

How can I go back to `undefined`? Basically I want to be able to select an option in the list that will go back to displaying all of the data. Below is my app on JSBin:

[App](http://jsbin.com/paxatiw/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a custom filter function

```
$scope.filterByGenre = function(item){

  if (!$scope.selectedGenre || $scope.selectedGenre == 'All'){
    return true;
  }

  return item.genre && item.genre.indexOf($scope.selectedGenre) != -1;

}
```

change your `<select>` to this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedGenre"
            ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in genres"
            name="genre"
            class="genre-dropdown">
</select>
```

change `<tr ng-repeat="...` filters to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:searchBar | filter:filterByGenre | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
```

**Online Demo - http://jsbin.com/riyafupexu/1/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: This is great! Except I actually have that HTML table inside a directive. I tried putting `$scope.filterByGenre` inside the `link` property of the directive, but it refuses to call it. **DISREGARD** ...I had a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, you are using `ng-options` but you also provided the static options.
For a quick fix in this case you can remove that ng-options and uncomment that `All` and remove it's value.

Like:

```
<select ng-model="selectedGenre"
        ng-change="handleSelect()"
        name="genre"
        class="genre-dropdown">
    <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
    <option value="Animation">Animation</option>
    <option value="Biography">Biography</option>
    <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
    <option value="Crime">Crime</option>
    <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
    <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
    <option value="History">History</option>
    <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
    <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
    <option value="Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</option>
    <option value="Western">Western</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
 $scope.selectedGenre = "";//set the model to blank.
    $scope.genres = 'All,Action,Adventure,Animation,Biography,Comedy,Crime,Drama,Fantasy,History,Horror,Romance,Sci-Fi,Western';
    //create an array after splitting the commas
    $scope.genresAry = $scope.genres.split(',');
    $scope.genresAry.push("");//push blank into the array.
```

In HTML use `genresAry`.

```
<select ng-model="selectedGenre"
                ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in genresAry"
                ng-change="handleSelect()"
                name="genre"
                class="genre-dropdown">
```

working code [here](http://jsbin.com/kubezitohi/1/edit?html,js,output)